# Check Contains condition based on comma separated values ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: arrays, csv, asp.net-core-mvc, contains

I have a question: I have two array values, one is custom class object which has a variable classification code and other, which is an array of values of that classificiation type. I need to check if values exists in classification code array and combine results to make one result. The values can be multiples or single and based on that I need to put them in contains filter.

For example at the moment for single value the code is.

```
private List<Result> FilterbyClassification(List<Result> results)
{
    var classificationCodes = "C, R".Split(",").ToList();
    return results.Where(f => classificationCodes.All(f.ClassificationCode.Contains)).ToList();
}
```

It is not giving me any values at the moment. Can you please help

Comment: What issue you are having in current implementation?

Comment: I simply do not know the elegant way of checking multiple values coming from csv in an array  to put them in contains, as the value will values are dynamic. In the above example, I simply used one value of array in contain, if you see arrayClassificationCode.ToUpper().Contains(values[0]);

Comment: Haven't seen any drawback in your code. In addition, `elegant` has no ultimate implementation as It’s completely arbitrary and needs centric.

Comment: Well I have not been able to apply my code for multiple values yet? that is why asking question, if there is a way to implement neat nicely, using linq etc.? I do not know the length of array of here, it will be dynamic

Comment: I got your point, so you don't know the length here right `ClassResult[]`? is it comma seperated string array? In addition, its alright if we don't know the length or value here `arrayClassificationCode` but we must know what we need to search here `values = "CP, RS".Split(",");` If you are agree , I would try to write a solution using linq.

Comment: I have just corrected valClassResult is not array but a custom class and it contains CCode value which has to be matched with "values" array. "values" array is dynamic valClassificationCode.CCode.ToUpper().Contains() should be able to check multiple values array in the contain block.

Comment: I have updated my code for you - I tried but it is not giving me any results, Both are arrays and I need to collate the results at the end. Please check again and let me know what is I am missing here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you'll need to check:

1. Remove the blank space in the `classificationCodes` declaration

```
var classificationCodes = "C,R".Split(",").ToList();
```

2. Change your Linq to use `Any` instead of `All` and use the comparison for the classification code. That should give you the result:

```
// items: 
        var items = new List<Result>
        {
            new Result { ClassificationCode = "C", Id = 1},
            new Result { ClassificationCode = "C", Id = 2},
            new Result { ClassificationCode = "R", Id = 3},
            new Result { ClassificationCode = "A", Id = 4}
        };
        var classificationCodes = "C,R".Split(",").ToList();

        var data = items.Where(x => classificationCodes.Any(y => y == x.ClassificationCode)).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(data));


// Output
[{"Id":1,"ClassificationCode":"C"},{"Id":2,"ClassificationCode":"C"},{"Id":3,"ClassificationCode":"R"}]
```

Alternatively, you can also you a linq join:

```
        var data = from i in items
            join cc in classificationCodes on i.ClassificationCode equals cc
            select new Result {ClassificationCode = i.ClassificationCode, Id = i.Id};
```

Or

```
        var data = items.Join(classificationCodes, i => i.ClassificationCode, cc => cc,
            (i, cc) => new Result {ClassificationCode = i.ClassificationCode, Id = i.Id});
```